# Format note field given date according to the given style

Tags: biblatex

I have the following entry in my biblio.bib:

```
@article{author1:2015,
  author={author1 and author2,
  title={Something good},
  journal={A very good journal},
  year=2015,
  month=jun,
  volume=26,
  pages={20--30},
  number=6,
  issn={1111-1111},
  note={Published online in December 2013},
}
```

And the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}

From a very good journal~\cite{author1:2015}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The question is: may I format the month and year in the `note` field according to style that is used for the fields `month` and `year`?

Comment: You may if you do it yourself. The `note` field is, in `biblatex`, a "literal field", which is "printed as is". You can style the whole field with `\DeclareFieldFormat`, but you can't (normally) operate on elements within the field.  With `backend=biber`, however, you can fiddle with things on the fly using regexp.  Might be easier to just fix the field yourself, though.

Comment: For me the `backend` is not a problem. So I can use `backend=biber`. The thing is, when you change style, you must come and change the field `note` also. Which is not good. That is why I wanted some automatic method.

Comment: What about `@preamble{ "\providecommand{\mystring}[2]{#1 and #2}" }` and then `note={Published online in \mystring{Dec.}{2013}},` ..? (Modify as needed --- e.g., set up something for months with `\ifcase`.)

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted. Where do you put this code? Inside `biblio.bib`?

Comment: Yes. And note that it is *provide* command.  That means you can have in your `.tex` file a `\newcommand\mystring[2]{Actually do #2 and #1}` and redefine it as necessary. Very portable.  Or, like I said, you could use the powers of Biber to change the actual input.

Comment: @jon I think that might be a sensible answer. Mind posting it as such? (I would be very interested in a Biber solution, as I could not figure one out that seemed feasible)

Comment: @moewe -- Will do, for the BibTeX part at least.  For, now I wonder about Biber!  If you didn't think of a good answer, I doubt I'll have much luck....

Comment: @jon Sorry to bother you again. I just stumbled about this again and wondered if you would like to add an answer.

Comment: @moewe -- Sorry! I forgot about this.  I wanted to look at an idea for Biber, but summer's proven to be really busy, and this got lost in the shuffle.  This weekend!

Answer (score 1):

The note field is, in biblatex, a "literal field", which is "printed as is". You can style the whole field with \DeclareFieldFormat, but you can't (normally) operate on elements within the field.

Here's a basic solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@preamble{ "\providecommand{\mystring}[2]{#1 and #2}" }
@article{author1:2015,
  author={author1 and author2},
  title={Something good},
  journal={A very good journal},
  year=2015,
  month=jun,
  volume=26,
  pages={20--30},
  number=6,
  issn={1111-1111},
  orignote={Published online in December 2013},
  note={Published online in \mystring{Dec.}{2013}},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

% \newcommand\mystring[2]{Actually do #2 and #1}
\begin{document}

From a very good journal~\cite{author1:2015}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The `\providecommand` provides a command if nothing is defined, so you can use `\newcommand` in the preamble as needed (it will be seen first).

The point of this solution is that you could `provide` a list of commands for each month in your `.bib` file with a basic format, and then redefine them in individual `.tex` files when you want.  Not pretty, really, but using the `note` field in this way doesn't align (in my opinion) with best practices to begin with. (And everyone knows that two hacks make it a-right.)

I believe a `\DeclareSourcemap` solution is feasible, but I don't have time these days to get one up and running. If no one else does so, I may try to revisit this answer (late) next month.  Note that this would require using Biber instead of BibTeX.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any idea for a Biber approach? My concepts all need some kind of way to tell Biber that the following in the `note` field needs to be a date.

Comment: @moewe -- No, not really. I can't remember what I was thinking a few weeks ago, but I don't think it was likely to be pretty or efficient.